# How to create a listener to a method in java

Tags: java, listener

I'm having a really bad time to implement a listener to a method.

In my current work i have to request a method every 5 seconds in order to verify for new information so i want to implement a method to notify me every time a new information come discarding the requesting method in every 5 seconds.

(I already read about observer pattern but had no successful in implementing.)

best regards

More information: 
For now i m overriding this method from the smack XMPP library in order to store new messages in msgs Queue

```
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
    if (message.getType() == Message.Type.chat) {
        req = message.getBody().toString();
        String[] temp = { chat.getParticipant().toString(), req };
        System.out.println(temp[0]+"says:"+temp[1]);
        synchronized (lock) {
            msgs.add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

and than i have this method executed every 0.5 seconds in order to verify new messages:

```
public String[] getMessage() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        String[] data;
        data=msgs.poll();
        return data;
    }
}
```

i'm trying to set a notification system that notifies me everytime the processMessage is executed.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is very hard to understand what you are asking. Please rephrase your question to be be more clear, preferably with some code that you have tried, the specific problem that you are facing and a *specific question* for us to answer.

Comment: Give us some code to work with please!

Comment: You still mention nothing about that method and what level of control you have over it. Is its code available? Can you modify it? Can you override it in a child class?

Comment: And most importantly you mention nothing about the update mechanism, which is what you would have to modify to intercept messages as they come...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok i manage to solve my problem.

I implemented a listener based on observer model. For that i had to implement a interface that i called XMPPmessageListener:

```
public interface XMPPmessageListener {
    public void readMsg(String senderJID, String msg); 
}
```

than in the XmppHandler class, the class of the methods processMessage and getMessage i added methods to add and remove listeners and a LinkedList to store the listeners:

```
private LinkedList<XMPPmessageListener> listeners = new LinkedList<XMPPmessageListener>();

public void addMsgListener(XMPPmessageListener listener){
    listeners.add(listener);
}

public boolean removeMsgListener(XMPPmessageListener listener){
    return listeners.remove(listener);
}
```

than i did some exchanges in processMessage method in order to warn the listeners:

```
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
    if (message.getType() == Message.Type.chat) {
        for(XMPPmessageListener l: listeners){
            l.readMsg(chat.getParticipant().toString(), message.getBody().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Now i can be notified at any method everytime a message is receive by creating a XMPPmessageListener and decide what to do with the message by overriding the readMsg method:

```
XmppHandler xmpp = new XmppHandler(XMPPuser, XMPPpassword, XMPPaddress, XMPPdomain, XMPPport);

XMPPmessageListener msglistener = new XMPPmessageListener() {

                @Override
                public void readMsg(String senderJID, String msg) {
                    String asw=xmlHandler.processMsg(msg,senderJID);

                }
            };
            xmpp.addMsgListener(msglistener);
```