# Listening for a listener

Tags: java, javafx

```
Class foo
{
    public void functionA()
    // do stuff
}

class bar
{
    private foo fooClass = new foo();

    private listener on foo.functionA() call
    {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

What I want to know is if this is even possible.

I'm currently using javafx, I have a group which contains a bunch of cylinders and when a cylinder is dragged I would like to call a function from a node above within the scene graph. The issue is I am not sure how far into the scene graph the cylinders are going to be, so calling `.getParent()` may not be the best course of action.

The main thing I am considering is the possibility of a listener listening for the event within the cylinder.

I'm not sure if this is the best explanation so sorry if it is confusing.

Essentially I am trying to edit a class when a listener is called. The class I am trying to edit has access to the listener class but not vice versa.

Comment: you want to execute an action when `functionA` method is invoked? or when the listener inside method receives an action?

Comment: may be this question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125870/how-to-create-a-listener-to-a-method-in-java

Comment: @JordiCastilla I want to invoke the listener event upon function A being called.

In the example I simplified it as a function but in reality it is a listener event.

Comment: and cheers, i'll give that answer a read. wow seems a lot more complex than I was hoping for.

Comment: Can you get the functionality you want just using [JavaFX Properties](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107)?

Comment: I have fixed the issue. I am writing a simple answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by sending the eventHandler to the lower object listener.

Example:

```
class foo
{
    public void setListeners(EventHandler handler)
    {
        this.setListener(handler);
    }
}

class bar
{
    foo fooObject = new foo();

    EventHandler eventH = new eventhandler()
    { 
        @override
        public void handle(event args)
        {
           functionToDo();
        }
    };

    private void functionToDo(){ do stuff }

    // call in some method
    {
        fooObject.setListeners(eventH);
    }
}
```

Now when the listener in foo is called (this can be done in many ways, but for my project it is a drag action), functionToDo will be called within bar.

I'm sure there is a better fix but this worked for me.